# Checking result by applying bear on file

Tags: python, coala, coala-bears

when i tried to check the bear results for a python file by using

> coala --bears AnnotationBear -f add.py --save

and when it asked for setting language- give "python", then on checking .coafile i didn't find any result that AnnotationBear has to give
so, how to check result?

Answer (score 0):

Hey the AnnotationBear yields, `HiddenResult` which are results meant to be used by other bears, and not be directly viewed by the user. If you are trying to test `coala`, you should check bears which actually give results, for eg: `PyFlakesBear`